# Screenshot every window you touch - Utility

Tags: screenshot

Is there a good (maybe free) app that can take a screenshot of every window you touch automatically? I'm writing a lot of training this week and it would sure help as I go between screens to have something automatically screenshoting and saving pics to my disk maybe.

Comment: What OS and version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not want to save every windows, or could want several screenshots for 1 window (after scrolling for instance, or selecting a different tab).

Use **[XnView](http://www.xnview.com/)** for the screenshots. Define a hotkey to trigger the capture. Select "Active Windows" and "Multiple Capture". The screenshots will be saved automatically to a predefined directory, without prompting for a filename.

[image]

Each time you have a windows worth saving, press on the hotkey.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is [Gadwin PrintScreen](http://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/). It has many options, can interface with other software products and is easy to use with an optional hotkey:

> There are several hotkey combos to
>   choose from (PrintScreen is the
>   default). Once you've chosen your
>   favorite combo, head to the
>   Destination tab and have the screen
>   print out instantly, copy the capture
>   to the clipboard, save it to a
>   specific folder, or even send it
>   through e-mail. You can perform full
>   screen captures, or only capture a
>   specific window.
>
> Gadwin PrintScreen is an easy to use
>   freeware utility that allows you to
>   capture any portion of the screen,
>   save it to a file, copy it to Windows
>   clipboard, print it or e-mail it to a
>   recipient of your choice.
>
> There are also six different image
>   formats to choose from, and each one
>   can be resized. With all the
>   customization capabilities, what more
>   could you ask for?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider capturing a video and grabbing individual frames after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, how about a little [**AutoHotkey**](http://autohotkey.com) ? You will need [**IrfanView**](http://www.irfanview.ca/) as well for the capture.

```
^LButton::
ifnotexist, C:\screenshots
fileCreateDir, C:\screenshots
Run, "C:\Program Files\IrfanView\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" /capture=1 /convert=C:\screenshots\capture_$U(`%Y-`%m-`%d_`%H`%M`%S).png
return
```

holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking will printscreen the active window, and save it to `C:\screenshots` with a timestamp and the `capture_` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it has the exact features you're looking for, but check out [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/).  It's designed for creating tutorials.  I know it has timed support, and I think it supports capturing every time you click, or something like that.  I remember that for web pages, I had to do an additional capture after the new page loaded because it didn't wait long enough for a web page to load, but I'm pretty sure that that's not an issue with a "real" application.

It will also allow you to save those screenshots as images or as a fancy flash app thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Windows tool called "Problem Steps Recorder". It takes screenshots of everything you do and compiles a HTML with those screenshots.

Comment: Upvote for suggesting one of the least used and least known in built features of Windows.